# MariaDB c api bind bit type

Tags: c++, mariadb-connector

I'm using Mariadb C api. Can I have an example of binding BIT type data? I can't find any of such examples on the Internet.

Here is part of my code

```
char** test_data = new char*[2];

test_data[0] = new char{'0'};

test_data[1] = new char{'1'};

MYSQL_BIND *bind = new MYSQL_BIND;

bind->buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_BIT;

bind->buffer = test_data;

mysql_stmt_attr_set(insertStmt, STMT_ATTR_ARRAY_SIZE, &numRows);

mysql_stmt_bind_param(insertStmt, bind);

mysql_stmt_execute(insertStmt);
```

The program crashes when executing the code.

I also tried

```
char** test_data = new char*[2];

test_data[0] = new char{'0'};

test_data[1] = new char{'1'};

MYSQL_BIND *bind = new MYSQL_BIND;

bind->buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;

bind->buffer = test_data;

mysql_stmt_attr_set(insertStmt, STMT_ATTR_ARRAY_SIZE, &numRows);
mysql_stmt_bind_param(insertStmt, bind);

mysql_stmt_execute(insertStmt);
```

And there is no data fetched back when doing so.

Comment: This is C++ and not C.

Comment: And please format your code properly!

Comment: I think the root of your issue is because you're mixing C++ concepts (like `new`) with C.

Comment: I think you should find the documentation what C++ type is mapped to `MYSQL_TYPE_BIT` or to `MYSQL_TYPE_STRING`. The way you allocate the memory looks suspicious

Comment: I use MariaDB c api in my C++ code. It works fine for all the other data types, except for MYSQL_TYPE_BIT. I don't think c vs c++ is the cause here.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko How would you write this in c? I would like an example that works.

Comment: @popcornhex I do not have the dev environment to create the sample code for you. At first ensure you really need to allocate the `MYSQL_BIND` on the heap. In the documentation this structure is allocated on the stack as array. Otherwise you need to `delete` after the SQL statement is executed. On MYSQL_TYPE_BIT see the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html. Also check the MYSQL source code. It seems you are missing `buffer_length` initialization.

Comment: @popcornhex For example of how to use the MYSQL_BIND instruction, see the unit test: https://github.com/google/mysql/blob/master/tests/mysql_client_test.c#L617